# sudo: dnf: command not found

Tags: software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 20.04. On Fedora/Red Hat or its derivatives,the installation can be performed using the following command:

```
sudo dnf install make gcc-c++
```

However, on Ubuntu it gives me

```
sudo: dnf: command not found
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What ae you trying to do? What do you mean by "I want to install On Fedora/Red Hat or its derivatives"? Where did you get this command?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu

Comment: I want to install QRNAS this program.İt s kind of bioinformatic software.To install this program,it requires these codes:The g++ compiler can be installed using the
following command on a Ubuntu, 
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install build-essential
On Fedora/Red Hat or its derivatives, the installation can be performed using the following
command:
$ sudo dnf install make gcc-c++
For openSUSE or its derivatives use the following command:
$ zypper install make gcc-c++
For Arch Linux use the following command:
$ pacman -S base-devel

Comment: how can I fix ?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, Ubuntu isn't Red Hat/CentOS, so Red Hat/CentOS specific package commands I wouldn't expect to work on non-RPM/CentOS/RedHat systems; adjust and use Debian/Ubuntu appropriate commands. Any additional detail belongs in your question; currently it's unclear as your question is "how can I fix using a redhat only command on ubuntu"; use `apt` & the appropriate Ubuntu package names?  The first comment asked for clarification on your question, it's still unchanged & unclear.

Comment: @guiverc I've suggested an edit to the question to make it clearer. Refer this pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIsfe.png. The GitHub page of QRNAS is https://github.com/sunandanmukherjee/QRNAS. I hope you'll be able to assist the author of the question now.

Comment: Ubuntu does not use `dnf`  If you read the instructins on that list you just put in comments, you need to use the Ubuntu commands in that guide - `sudo apt install build-essential`

Comment: This post is not a duplicate post. The author of the question didn't frame their question in a proper manner. The author wants to install QRNAS as mentioned [in this comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2180824). Searching 'QRNAS' in DDG will give us [this PDF](https://bmcstructbiol.biomedcentral.com/track/pdf/10.1186/s12900-019-0103-1). In page 10 of the PDF, there's a link under the "Availability and requirements" paragraph. The link is http://genesilico.pl/software/stand-alone/qrnas. If we go to the link there's a paragraph named "Installation".

Comment: We can notice that the steps mentioned under the paragraph are exactly the same as what the author has mentioned [in this comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2180824) and also in the question. The author *probably* doesn't know the difference between APT and DNF.

Comment: OP included the commands required. The target posts deal with their issues with those commands. If they have further problems with the installation, they can edit this question or ask a new one.